# Add Wireless Adapter to RaspberryPi

Tags: networking, hardware, wireless

I want to connect my PI to the internet using my old Wireless Dongle Netgear WG111.

According to this [blog post](http://grimtech.net/?p=213) I did the following:

1. Edit the file: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and append the following:

   ```
   network={
       ssid="MyNetwork"
       psk="MyPassword"
   }
   ```
2. Make sure the interface is listed using the command `lsusb` which did output the adapter:

   ```
   ...
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:4240 NetGear, Inc. WG111(v1) rev 2 54 Mbps Wireless [Intersil ISL3887]
   ```
3. Start the interface by using the command `sudo ifup wlan0`. But this resulted in the following erros:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
   run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
   Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
   wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
   run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
   ```
4. When I now run this command again it tells me `ifup: interface wlan0 already configured` but if I run `ifconfig` the interface is not there.

I don't see what I've done wrong so suggestions and advice are very welcome.

**Update**

Here are the contents of the related files.

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MyNetwork"
    psk="b90c69cbcacbb3f7c53db25cf63193ad8a828c7a317401d450017172b99d2ed2"
}
```

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: @MNoit I did update my post with the contents. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, you have posted the output of `lsusb` with the Vendor ID.

This particular release of the old Netgear WG111 seems to need the `p54usb` driver. If

```
modprobe p54usb
```

gives nothing, please have a look at [Linux Wireless](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/p54#p54) for further information and the firmware.

Whether it is really worth the effort is of course up to you.

Answer (score 1):

As your dongle is old, it may not work with raspberry pi. My old dongle doesn't. You could buy a wipi, a dongle made for raspberry pi, or you could connect via your computer. Instructions for connection via computer at: [http://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/.](http://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same `wpa_supplicant` errors, except using an EDUP (realtek) wifi adapter.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

For me the errors were most likely caused by an `rpi-update` that was interrupted and failed before finishing, which meant that after rebooting the `8192cu` kernel module was not loaded.

I fixed it by copying the modules under the old kernel folder `/lib/modules/3.xx.yy/kernel/drivers/net/wireless` to the new (eg. from 3.12.18 to 3.12.20), then running `depmod -a`, and finally rebooting.